# Changing the main launcher activity programmatically

Tags: android

My app works as launcher. 10 mins later another activity starts automatically. When this activity started, if user presses home button, he returns to the main activity. However, I want to change the launcher activity as the second one. It must be forbidden to return to the main activity even if he presses home button.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of playing around with the intent filters, I suggest you create a blank Activity, with no UI, and register it as your launcher.
This Activity's sole role is to choose the correct actual Activity you wanna show, launch it as a new task, and then quit silently.

Comment: Yes it must be the solution.. I liked this answer :) Thank you.. Actually, I have some things to do. When I finished them, I'll apply your answer. If I have a question about it, is it possible to ask it here?

Comment: Yes. Of course - this is the point of this site :) And, if you're happy with the answer, please mark it as the correct one for future readers.